# Finding the worst cost of search of the optimal tree

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-search-tree

Here's my problem. I have a sorted list of integers. My objective is to find the worst cost of search of the optimal binary search tree. The cost is computed by adding the number of each node used to find the number. (We do not add the number).

For example, the worst cost of the OBST of the 4 first squares goes like this : [link to the illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVRS0.png). (N.B: the leaves do not count in the cost)
The worst cost of the optimal tree would be 10.

I have tried a lot of things but I cannot find a good algorithm (I need the very best, but can't use brute force).

```
long long maxRootLeafSum(const vector<long long>& v ){
long long sum = 0;

switch (v.size())
{
case 0:
    sum = 0;
    break;
case 1:
    sum = 0;
    break;
case 2:
    sum = v[0];
    break;
case 3:
    sum = v[1];
    break;
case 4:
    sum = v[0] + v[2];
    break;
default:
    long long leftCost = 0, rightCost = v[v.size() - 2], i = 0, j = 0;

    for (i = v.size() - 4; i >= j; i -= 2)
    {
        rightCost += v[i];
        for (; leftCost < rightCost; ++j)
            leftCost += v[j];

    }
    sum = min(leftCost, rightCost);
    break;
}

return sum;
```

}

This may work for some cases, but not always. I figured out that under 4 nodes, I could compute right away the result. I believe there might be a way to find the best root node for a given set of data. If so, I could use a recursive function to find the worst cost of the best tree. Maybe I'm also totally not on the right track!

Thank you!

Comment: Can we assume a complete binary tree? That is, all levels of the binary tree are completely filled, with the possible exception of the last level, which is left-filled. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Types_of_binary_trees for an example of a complete binary tree.

Comment: @JimMischel - Why make such an assumption? The requirements are very clear and don't include this feature. It *might* be the case for all inputs but that needs to be proven, not assumed.

Comment: As Amit said, we can not assume a complete binary tree. Thank you!

Comment: You're right. I was assuming a standard binary search tree. I overlooked the "optimal" part, in which case a complete tree is not a valid assumption.

Comment: Hint: The worst-case search time is equal to what simple property of the BST?  Now instead of trying to arrange *your particular set of n given numbers* into a BST that minimises this property, suppose that we don't actually know what the n numbers are, only that we have n of them.  Now (a) pack these n nodes into a BST-shaped tree that minimises the property, and then (b) show that, given *any* set of n numbers, *some permutation* of them could be arranged into a *valid* BST with the same shape.